# VBA syntax on SetCell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, syntax

I currently need a help to fix the code below.

```
SetCell:="$M$30", MaxMinVal:=2, Valueof:="0", ByChange:="$D$4:$D$28"
```

The error was `compile error: syntax error`.

Comment: You didn't even spend the time to spellcheck the error message. It's unclear what your code should be doing. As it is, it just seems to be a number of assignments. What have you actually tried to fix it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

*Excel never allows the Solver to use more than one executing parameters as you have used*,

`SetCell:="$M$30", MaxMinVal:=2, Valueof:="0", ByChange:="$D$4:$D$28"`.

Your syntax should be either with `MaxMinVal` or `Valueof` like,,

```
SetCell:="$M$30", Valueof:="0", ByChange:="$D$4:$D$28".
```

**or**

```
SetCell:="$M$30", MaxMinVal:=2, ByChange:="$D$4:$D$28"
```

**NB:** You need to decide which one is required.

*Hope this help you.*